# Cell height not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I used the following code to change the cell height dynamically. But it does not show anything. Can anyone help me to do that.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(!self.customCell){
        self.customCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }

    //Cell configuration
    self.customCell.title.text = vendor[indexPath.row];

    int quoteIndex = indexPath.row % [vendor count];
    self.customCell.description.text = message[quoteIndex];

    //Cell Layout
    [self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];

    //Height of cell
    CGFloat height = [self.customCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    //    CGFloat height = 240;

    return height;
}
```

Comment: do you use AutoLayout? also I found this: [dynamic table cells](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/02/14/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html). Does it not show anything at all? Did you set the delegate and dataSource?

Comment: Yes.. I set the delegate and datasource. Its simply showing the empty cells. I dont know how to check the autolayout is on or off

Comment: CGFloat height = [self.customCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height is not working

Comment: just click in the storyboard on a view and look out in the file inspector under 'Interface Builder Document'. If it's a new project it should be automatically use auto layout. Then maybe it would be interesting what's the content of your custom cell. Maybe something prevents it from shrinking/extending. Also at the link I posted, they suggest to have a kind of prototype cell for layouting and calculating the height.

Comment: hey, just test [self.customCell.contentView systemLayoutSi....] instead of only calling it for self.customCell

Comment: self.customCell is not working

Comment: cell configuration better in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In custom cell, Description label - set number of lines = 0

**[Lable SizeToFit]** will help you.

This code may be help you.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(!self.customCell){
        self.customCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }

    //Cell configuration
    self.customCell.title.text = vendor[indexPath.row];

    int quoteIndex = indexPath.row % [vendor count];
    self.customCell.description.text = message[quoteIndex];

    [self.customCell.description sizeToFit];

    float height = (CGRectGetMaxY(self.customCell.description.frame) + 5);
    return height;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: its working fine. But the contents in the cell shows single line only. Its not showing the full content

Comment: Please check for label's property - number of lines whether it is set to 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

You are using same reference to refer to cell but you have to create seperate cell reference inside like following:

```
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     static CustomCell *customCell = nil;
     static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, {
           customCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
        });

// Rest of your code

    }
```